# Magento2: How can solve cache issue when do redirection to login page?

Tags: magento2

I am facing issue of cache. I have added condition if customer not logged then user will redirect to login page every time. but it is working only one time and when I clear cache then again it work.
please see my code below. I am using this code in footer.phtml file.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
    if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $customerSession->authenticate();
    }
```

Anyone have an idea for that? How can fix this. I can not disabled cache from admin for that. so I want other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue is happening because of `$objectManager`.

PLease do not use $objectManager directly. Create function in block OR helper and use that.

ELSE

Use `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` instead of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`.

You can use below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSessionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory');
if($customerSessionFactory->create()->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSessionFactory->create()->authenticate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have used object manger code of your, it is giving still same issue. then I used with footer.php file using block but not working.

Comment: I have tried all option but still facing issue. kindly help me for this.

Comment: @RaviVarma have clear cache and check that in private window or clear browser cache. My code will work definately

Comment: Okay. I have added not sign "!" like !$customerSessionFactory->create()->isLoggedIn()   It is redirecting, but it is giving error 'This page isn’t working redirected you too many times.'. I have cleared all chache, cokkies etc. check multiple browser, nut getting too-many redirect issue

Comment: @RaviVarma 'This page isn’t working redirected you too many times.' This is browser chache and cookies issue .

Comment: @RaviVarma check these links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507584/magento-has-a-redirect-loop and https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Error-too-many-redirects/td-p/89153

Comment: Actually I have disabled cache of "Block html output" from admin after that url reiredting other wise code was getting same issue. please find screenshot : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/g632  I have checked now different different systems and different browsers also but it give too many redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87272/discussion-between-ravi-varma-and-mukesh-prajapati).